# Firestore Security Rules: How to get document and check if resource property is true

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need some help writing a Firestore security rule.

I have a subcollection called `posts` like the following example path:

`/users/XrMD3azk4Jess5KNTSICv4RYEj02/posts/what-architecture-style-is-this_r3nosJHQIt`

I am building a "mystery blog" app where users can submit mysteries (aka, "posts") and other users can provide answers (aka, "comments") to the mystery post. If the mystery post author feels that the provided comment solves the mystery, then the post author can go ahead and click a button labeled "Select as answer".

Example screenshot:

[image]

The answer is saved to a subcollection called `answers` in the user's record (the user that provided the answer, aka "doss"). This is an example path with screenshot:

[image]

**This works fine.**
However, I obviously only want the post author to be allowed to press the "select as answer" button...and I will write the front-end logic for that so that button only appears for the post owner. **But, how can I correctly write the back-end firestore rule to prevent a non-post owner user from maliciously trying to edit/select an answer?**

I assume that I need to check the post author's id (aka, `uid`) and see if it matches the signed in user's `uid`.

This is what I tried, but I get permission errors here:

```
  match /users/{uid}/answers/{docId} {
    allow read;
    allow write: if request.auth != null; && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/posts/$(id)).data.uid == uid
  }
```

Here's an example of the post document that contains the author's `uid` and the post `id`:

[image]

Thanks for any help or pointers!

Answer (score 0):

So I went a different path just to make this a bit easier on the security rule logic and maintenance.

I simply added a `postUid` property when creating the `answer` doc:

```
    async selectAsAnswer(comment) {
      const answerDoc = this.$fire.firestore
        .collection(`users/${this.comment.uid}/answers`)
        .doc()
      await answerDoc.set({
        id: answerDoc.id,
        commentId: comment.id,
        postId: comment.postId,
        postUid: this.post.uid,
        createdAt: this.$fireModule.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        commentUid: comment.uid
      })
    }
```

Then, in the security rule for this answer document I checked for the `postUid` property match:

```
  match /users/{uid}/answers/{docId} {
    allow read;
    allow create, update: if signedInAndVerified() && request.resource.data.postUid == request.auth.uid;
  }
```

This seems to work fine and it just makes the overall DX a bit easier.